# coredata .xcdatamodel creats a wrong .mom, lead to can not set value for new property, is there any solution?

Tags: ios, core-data

today I new some attribures in entities, then got a error like this:

```
LOLHelper[3393:101073] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MatchList_EN setSummonerName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800048f370'
```

then I found I can not find new column/item in .sqlist/.mom file, I have no idea.

I already recreated (NSManagedObject subclass) MatchList_EN, it has a new property named summonerName, i tried to recreated NSManagedObject subclass, uninstall and install app, create new version .xcdatamodel, but all do not work.

paty of code is here:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * contextMatchList_EN = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        NSPersistentContainer * psc =[[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"LOLHelper"];
        [psc loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription * storeDescription, NSError * error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                abort();
            }
        }];

        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LOLHelper" withExtension:@"momd"];
        NSLog(@"%@", modelURL);

        [contextMatchList_EN setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc.persistentStoreCoordinator];
        parentContext = contextMatchList_EN;
        [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{

//            MatchList_EN * MatchList_ENEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MatchList_EN" inManagedObjectContext:parentContext];

            MatchList_EN * MatchList_ENEntity = [[MatchList_EN alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MatchList_EN" inManagedObjectContext:parentContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:parentContext];

            ///存储所有的属性名称
             NSMutableArray *allNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            ///存储属性的个数
             unsigned int propertyCount = 0;

            ///通过运行时获取当前类的属性
            objc_property_t *propertys = class_copyPropertyList([MatchList_ENEntity class], &propertyCount);

            NSLog(@"class is %@", NSStringFromClass(MatchList_ENEntity.class));
            //把属性放到数组中
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i ++) {
                ///取出第一个属性
                objc_property_t property = propertys[i];

                const char * propertyName = property_getName(property);

                [allNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyName]];
                NSLog(@"propert is %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:propertyName]);
                }

            ///释放
             free(propertys);

            if (matchListM != nil) {
                [matchListM setValue:[[self getSummonerInfo_EN] objectForKey:@"accountId"] forKey:@"accountId"];
                [matchListM setValue:[[self getSummonerInfo_EN] objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"summonerName"];
                for (key in matchListM.allKeys) {
                    value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[matchListM objectForKey:key]];
                    if ([key isEqualToString:@"summonerName"]) {
                        MatchList_ENEntity.summonerName = value;
                    }
                    [MatchList_ENEntity setValue:value forKey:key];
                }
//                [gameIdArr addObject:[matchList objectForKey:@"gameId"]];
            }
```

I also check the class type of ManagedObject and its properties, however it is right!!!!

```
2017-07-16 00:48:14.173901+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] class is MatchList_EN
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174073+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is accountId
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174169+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is assistMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174302+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is assists
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174476+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is champion
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174591+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is damageMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.174862+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is deaths
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175039+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is doubleKill
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175233+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is endIndex
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175407+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is gameCreation
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175514+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is gameId
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175640+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is gameMode
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175772+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is gameType
2017-07-16 00:48:14.175931+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is killMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.176189+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is kills
2017-07-16 00:48:14.176455+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is lane
2017-07-16 00:48:14.176632+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is minionMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.176915+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is moneyMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.177136+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is mvp
2017-07-16 00:48:14.177367+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is pentaKill
2017-07-16 00:48:14.177613+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is platformId
2017-07-16 00:48:14.177784+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is quadraKill
2017-07-16 00:48:14.177975+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is queue
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178073+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is role
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178224+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is season
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178418+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is startIndex
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178576+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is summonerName
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178746+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is takenMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.178865+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is timestamp
2017-07-16 00:48:14.179049+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is totalGames
2017-07-16 00:48:14.179188+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is tripleKill
2017-07-16 00:48:14.179313+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is turretMost
2017-07-16 00:48:14.179507+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is win
2017-07-16 00:48:14.179663+0800 LOLHelper[3393:101073] propert is listToMatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the answer:
cause after Xcode 8, there is a new feature about coredata, Xcode will automaticlly create NSManagedObject in DerivedShources folder(DerivedData/project).
so can delete the project in DerivedData, or change .xcdatamodel's option named tools version below Xcode 8, then fix it.